# Generate a barcode - app runs error free but does not generate a barcode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

recently I have managed to get the app to work properly with no errors.

The problem is that it is supposed to generate a barcode with text underneath; what it does, it only generates an image with text - no barcode.

I am using the font IDAutomationHC39M. The app should convert the text into a barcode.

Please see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String barcode = pole.Text;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 150);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush White = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(White, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", ofont, black, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                box.Image = bitmap;
                box.Height = bitmap.Height;
                box.Width = bitmap.Width;
            }
        }

        private void pole_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use another font, like Arial instead of the barcode font?

Comment: A get same blank image with text underneath

Comment: Blank in the box?  Is box a picturebox? Your code works fine here: Text on a white background.

Comment: Other issues are that you dipose neither the font nor the two brushes. And that the memorystream seems to do bothing at all..

Comment: I will try a different barcode font in a minute, maybe the system doesn't recognize it properly

Comment: That's a good idea; I found one that works and one that doesn't. But: If it doen's the result was Sans Serif, not blank.  [This one works](http://de.fontriver.com/font/idautomationhc39m/)

Comment: I might have said it wrong. I mean the image is generated with text only, it does not generate a barcode. And exactly like you say, in sans serif. When I type 123123123 in textbox and press generate, I get *123123123* only without a barcode.

Comment: Try the font I have linked to! It works fine.. The other one was not even recognized as a TrueType font and couldn't be used in the designer (although one of my older programms did manage to use it) - Btw for black and white you can and should use the standard brushes: `Brushes.Black and Brushes.White`. No need to create or dispose with a standard brush.. Also: the calculation for the width is rather crude. Use Graphics.MeasureText instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few minor issues in you code, namely the leaking of GDI resources and the inexact measurement of the bitmap you create.

Here is a version that takes care of those issues:

```
    String barcode = "*" + pole.Text + "*";
    PointF point = new PointF(5f, 5f);
    float fontHeight = 20f;
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(123,123);
    using (Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", fontHeight))
    {    // create a Graphics object to measure the barcode
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            Size sz = Size.Round(graphics.MeasureString( barcode, ofont));
            bitmap = new Bitmap(sz.Width + 10, sz.Height + 10);
        } // create a new one with the right size to work on
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.DrawString(barcode, ofont, Brushes.Black, point);
        }
    }
    box.Image = bitmap;
    box.ClientSize = bitmap.Size;

    // bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

**But your main problem** most likely comes from using a not fully compatible Font. There are many free fonts out there and not all work equally well.

I found [this font](http://de.fontriver.com/font/idautomationhc39m/) to work just fine but couldn't get [this one to work directly](http://www.dafont.com/de/idautomationhc39m.font), although one of my older programs, that enumerates the installed fonts, did work with it. But even the designer refused to use it, so it's not just the name..

Here is a sample :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the fonts you mention are exactly the ones I use but it still only generates the letter and digits instead of barcode itself.

Comment: Did you try my code? And the right one (the 1st one) ? The barcode font does generate smallish letters etc below the bars. I have added an image..

Comment: Now it works, I had to make some changes and it works magic. Thank you, appreciate your help

Comment: One more thing that I struggle with is that I would like to get this generated in another form (form2). So as soon as I click generate, new window will pop up and it will use a picture box (box2) in form2. I tried  var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();     but I think I will need to change the aforementioned code in order to redirect it to new window.

Comment: Many way to do that; the best depends on all those things you want to do with the form.. Here is the simplest one `Form barForm = new Form();
    PictureBox barBox = new PictureBox();
    barBox.Parent = barForm;
    barBox.Image = bitmap;
    barBox.ClientSize = bitmap.Size;
    barForm.ClientSize = barBox.Size;
    barForm.Show();`